# How to stop publishing a new version of extension that is marked as 'Pending Review' in chrome store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I've published a new version of the extension. It has been marked as 'Pending Review' because the manifest has some permission changes. 
Now I don't want the new version of the extension to be published. Is there any way to stop it? I just want to let the users continue using the already published version of the extension

(I don't know where else to ask)

Comment: @IvánNokonoko Unpublishing will remove it from the store. I only want to stop the update and let the user install and continue using the existing version of the extension. I've edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: If the cancel button is available, then you can select it. But if not, then you need to wait for the review team to finish the review. Usually review process takes up to 1 week base on my experience.

Comment: Do you know what triggers a review? My extension is stuck in this status for 3 days now. I did not change the permissions.

Comment: @GergelySzabo No, it takes about 12-24 hours max with the permission changes. Usually, it doesn't cross 4-5 hours without permission changes. But since this is not documented, I'm not sure why it is under review days for you.

Comment: Thanks, few hours was what I was seeing so far for the past 6 months that I have been pushing new versions of my extension.

Comment: @GergelySzabo Coincidentally, my extension is also stuck for 2 days now.

Comment: I am day 6. Talked to CWS developer support yesterday and they confirmed that it can take up to seven days but offered no explanation to what triggers a manual review.

Comment: The Pending Review can take up to 2 weeks or even months. This is a really bad state to be in with Google Chrome it seems.

Comment: Our extension stays in pending review ~1 week every time we publish update since Dec 2019. Really annoying. We have to distribute critical fixes in zip files and ask our customer to load extension unpacked. :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unfortunately this is still an issue as of today (8/14/2020) and there is no way to cancel a submission for review.

A recent change when submitting an extension for review there is an option to automatically publish the extension after passing the review. This is checked by default in the window prompt. As a practice I would recommend not allowing publication after a review to provide you with the final decision when the extension is published to the Chrome Web Store.

[image: submission modal]

Answer (score 14):

There now is a defer option. Just used it for the first time so hope it works as expected!

[image: Defer publish]

Edit: After the deferred item is approved you can select cancel publish from the menu. After canceling you are able to upload an updated package. Would love to just be able to cancel while it is waiting for approval, but this is at least a way!

[image: cancel publish]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Developer Dashboard for your extension and click on **Send Feedback** in the lower left-hand corner:
[image]
From there you'll be able to make your request directly to the Chrome Extension Support team.

Comment: This will takes long. Just waiting is enough.

Comment: Does the "Defer Publish" allow you to immediately upload a new package after they approve the release, without risk of it pushing to users?